# How to use or install oid2name?

Tags: postgresql

As referenced here: https://postgreshelp.com/postgresql-checkpoint

And in the pg docs
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/contrib-prog.html

=> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/contrib-prog-client.html

=> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/oid2name.html

it appears to be something to do with contrib.

I am running server version 9.5.20 psql version 8.4.20 on centos 6.7

I have installed (I think) the contrib package using

```
yum install postgresql-contrib
```

although when I execute `postgresql-contrib`

I get

`-bash: postgresql-contrib: command not found`

If I execute `create extension oid2name` (I'm not sure if I should need to do this given the documentation referenced above, but anyway...) I get

`create extension oid2name; ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.5/share/extension/oid2name.control": No such file or directory`

and what is in that directory?

```
~$ ls /usr/pgsql-9.5/share/extension/    
plpgsql--1.0.sql  plpgsql.control  plpgsql--unpackaged--1.0.sql
```

I am in an unfamiliar area..but like many things it should not be so difficult if you know how.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed the CentOS binaries for 9.5, `oid2name` can be called with its absolute path like this:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/oid2name
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not there. I'm not sure what exactly is meant by installing the CentOS binaries for 9.5 though; I run postgres inside a VM (a Vagrant box).  My bin dir is `/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/` and oid2name is not there.

Comment: I've just found it - it's at `/usr/bin/oid2name`.  For some reason my pg binaries are in `/usr/bin` .. I just saw eg pgbench in /usr/bin and lo! there's oid2name and a bunch of other stuff too.

Comment: With the CentOS binaries I meant the PGDG packages from the PostgreSQL site. But there are many ways to install it.

Answer (score 1):

`oid2name` is not an extension, it is an executable binary.  You execute it from the bash shell prompt, not from inside `psql`

Comment: That's what I thought and that's what I tried but it doesn't work.  But thanks anyway.